# angular http service not working ...why?

Tags: angularjs

//show movie list 100

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Movie search App</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="controller.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="movies">

 <ul>
     <h1>IMDB 100 Movies</h1>

     <li ng-repeat="movie in movies">

      {{ movie.title }}



     </li>


 </ul>

    enter code here

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

//json file

```
{
    "records":

[

  {
        "title": "The Shawshank Redemption",
        "rank": "1",
        "id": "tt0111161"
    },
    {
        "title": "The Godfather",
        "rank": "2",
        "id": "tt0068646"
    },
```

// controller.js

```
var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('movies', function ($scope,$http) {

    $http.get('localhost/SPA/movies.json');

    .success(function(responce))

    {

         $scope.movies=responce.records; 

    }

});
```

Comment: get rid of the semicolon after the get

Comment: And don't use success() which is deprecated since 1.4 or 1.5, and doesn't exist anymore in 1.6. Use then(). Also, the correct spelling is response, not responce.

Comment: Change `$http.get('localhost/SPA/movies.json');` to `$http.get('localhost/SPA/movies.json')` i.e, remove semicolon.  `$http` returns promise and on that only you can use success function but by placing `;` you are terminating the line

Answer (score 3):

Remove `;` from this line:

```
$http.get('localhost/SPA/movies.json');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `controller.js` to:

```
var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('movies', function ($scope,$http) {
    $http.get('localhost/SPA/movies.json').success(function(responce) {
         $scope.movies=responce.records; 
    });
```